# error: 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, inheritance

I've a code as follows -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A{
    int a;
    public: virtual void sayHello(){ std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
};

class B : private A{
    std::string name;
  public:
    B(std::string _n): name(_n){}
    void sayName(){std::cout << name << "says hello\n";}
    void sayHello(){sayName();}
};


int main() {
    A *ptr = new B("c++");
    ptr->sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the following compiler output -

> Error:
>
> ```
> prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> prog.cpp:20:22: error: 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'
>   A *ptr = new B("c++");
>                       ^
> ```

As previously answered - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661936/inheritance-a-is-an-inaccessible-base-of-b), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847100/c-inheritance-inaccessible-base) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870020/why-am-i-getting-the-error-a-is-an-inaccessible-base-of-b-when-using-dynamic-c), I know how to solve this issue. By using `public` inheritence instead of `private` or `protected`.

But if I really really want to hide some interface behind the base class, isn't there some other way to do this? Or is it impossible to do so according to c++ lang specification.

Comment: What, specifically, do you want to do? Your question says that you don't want `A` to be accessible through `B` but that you do want `A` to be accessible through `B`. I suspect a design problem...

Comment: Well you made the inheritance to A private. So no-one knows that B inherits from A. There may be some edge-cases for private or protected inheritance but not here. And the fact that you assign B to a `A*` means you don't want to hide the interface.

Comment: The usage of `A*` to point to an object of type `B` is allowed only if `A` is an "accessible base" of `B`. If you want to hide the fact the `A` is a base of `B`, it doesn't make sense for the user to hold it with a pointer to `A`.

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492132/how-can-i-remove-refactor-a-friend-dependency-declaration-properly) helpful.

Comment: "*But if I really really want to hide some interface behind the base class, isn't there some other way to do this?*" If you allowed people to convert `B*` to `A*`, then the interface *wouldn't be hidden*, would it? Your question seems based on a contradiction. Perhaps you could provide more details on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @YehezkelB. - it's not the **use** of the pointer that isn't allowed; it's the **conversion** of a `B*` to an `A*`. If, for example, the class provided a member function `A* get_base_pointer() { return this; };` there would be nothing wrong with using the resulting pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, "conversion" is the correct and accurate word here. Your example, BTW, still needs to point the accessibility (or lack of it). From inside `B`, `A` is accessible, of course.

Comment: @PeteBecker indeed this is a design problem from my end, I'm still tinkering with it. I've a base class which can be instantiated, as well as its derived classes too. Now I've a few public class methods in base class that will be used in derived classes, but I don't want them to be exposed to derived classes' objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want polymorphic pointer conversion to work outside the class, then the inheritance must be public. There is no way to work around that.

You could add a member function that does the polymorphic pointer conversion within the class:

```
class B : private A{
    // ...
public:
    A* getA() {
        return this;
    }
};
```

Which allows you to do this, while still allowing private inheritance:

```
B* b_ptr = new B("c++");
A* ptr   = b_ptr->getA();
// ptr   = b_ptr; // only allowed in member functions
```

I haven't encountered a real world design where this trick would be useful, but suit yourself.

---

PS. Remember that you should destroy objects that you create. Also do realize that `delete ptr` has undefined behaviour, unless `~A` is virtual.

Comment: "There is no way to work around that." This is actually untrue; there is a workaround: C style casts

Answer (score 2):

Even though I find it quite strange to hide the base class and want to cast `B` to `A`, you can use for that the `operator A*()`.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A{
    int a;
public:
    virtual void sayHello(){ std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
};

class B : private A{
    std::string name;
public:
    B(std::string _n): name(_n){}
    operator A*() { return this; }
    void sayName(){std::cout << name << "says hello\n";}
    void sayHello(){sayName();}
};
```

Now you can use it as:

```
int main() {
    A *ptr = *(new B("c++"));
    ptr->sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

Or even better:

```
int main() {
    B b{"c++"};
    A *ptr = b;
    ptr->sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

Adding the cast to `A&` is as easy as adding the member method `operator A&()` defined as `return *this;`.

Comment: any gotchas with this method?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I find it easier to use in regard of `getA`, mainly when passing the object as a function argument, but one can argue that's unclear what's going on under the hood. I don't know, this is an alternative, it's up to you if you find it useful or not. ;-)

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal Oh, yeah, it is not implicitly called when you assign a pointer to `B` to a pointer to `A`, for it's a member method of `B` and you have to have an instance or a reference to an instance of `B`, as shown in the example in the answer.

Comment: and memory will be managed on stack, right? no call for delete necessary as long as `B b{"c++"}` lives..

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal This is true, but it's an example. You can do whatever you want, see the first example where I still use `new`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an unsightly way around this: C style casts. C style casts can cast to inaccessible base classes. This is the one and only case where C style casts can do something that C++ casts can't. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), when a C style cast `(T) foo` attempts to perform `static_cast<T>(foo)`, it can do slightly more than just a `static_cast`:

> [P]ointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) *even if the base class is inaccessible* (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier).

<sup>Emphasis added</sup>

Thus, you can do this:

```
int main() {
    A *ptr = (A *) new B("c++");
    ptr->sayHello();
    return 0;
}
```

This is ugly, and it comes with all the disadvantages of casting and especially of C style casts. But it does work, and it is allowed.

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L6qqiz2FXLighXYo)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to hide that `A` is a base of `B` this is valid.

But you assignment

```
A *ptr = new B("c++");
```

breaks this hiding, because you use an `A*`. So c++ generates an error because the dependency is hidden. You can do

```
B *ptr = new B("c++");
```

though.